# What is the difference between `this` and `prototype`? javascript oop

Tags: javascript, oop

While going through javascript course on codecademy.com, I've become slightly confused.

*So first we've been learning how to add method to a Class:*

```
function Dog (breed) {
    this.breed = breed;
    this.sayHello = function () {
        console.log("Hello this is a " + this.breed + " dog");
    }
};
var someDog = new Dog("golden retriever");
someDog.sayHello();
```

*Then we started the "prototype". And there was this example:*

```
function Dog (breed) {
    this.breed = breed;
};
Dog.prototype.sayHello = function () {
    console.log("Hello this is a " + this.breed + " dog");
}
var someDog = new Dog("golden retriever");
someDog.sayHello();
```

Both examples are giving the same result. 
Are these two examples are just two ways doing same thing? Or there is a practical difference between two of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that in the second case, all instances share the same `sayHello` function. That's more efficient, especially if you create a lot of instances.

Answer (score 2):

The ***prototype*** method sayHello is shared by all instances of the class Dog as opposed to adding it with ***this*** in the constructor which creates a fresh copy for each instance, wasting space and time.

Here is how the ***new*** operator works in words:

https://gist.github.com/Havvy/5037770

Here is how the ***new*** operator works using a picture:

[image]